# One character diff - string comparison

Tags: c#, strings, interview-questions, edit-distance

The question was:

> Create an algorithm to check if two strings differ by one character.

This wasn't my interview, so I tried to understand the question.

Options:

1. just compare the chars one by one, I assume the lower case and uppercase isn't the same.
2. compare the chars in any given order meaning "tube" and "bute" are the same...

Please be as strict as you can and find my bugs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{   

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter some text");    
            string stringToCheck1 = "Out";
            string stringToCheck2 = "tuo";

            bool result = CompareStrings(stringToCheck1, stringToCheck2);
            PrintMessage(result);
            result = CompareAllLetters(stringToCheck1, stringToCheck2);
            PrintMessage(result);
        }
        public void PrintMessage(bool result)
        {
            if (result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Strings are less than one letter apart");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Strings are more than one letter apart");            
        }

        //checks if the letters one by one
        public static bool CompareStrings(string stringToCheck1, string stringToCheck2)
        {
            //check if strings are not the same size 
            if (Math.Abs(stringToCheck2.Length - stringToCheck1.Length) > 2)
            {
                return false;
            }

            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < stringToCheck1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (stringToCheck1[i] != stringToCheck2[i])
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if (counter > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //checks if the letters in any order
        public static bool CompareAllLetters(string stringToCheck1, string stringToCheck2)
        {
            //check if strings are not the same size 
            if (Math.Abs(stringToCheck2.Length - stringToCheck1.Length) > 2)
            {
                return false;
            }

            List<char> string1LettersList = new List<char>();
            List<char> string2LettersList = new List<char>();
            foreach (var c in stringToCheck1)
            {
                string1LettersList.Add(c);
            }

            foreach (var c in stringToCheck2)
            {
                string2LettersList.Add(c);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < string1LettersList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (string2LettersList.Contains(string1LettersList[i]))
                {
                    string2LettersList.Remove(string1LettersList[i]);
                }
            }
            if (string2LettersList.Count > 2)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *..and find my bugs* - fair enough, but does it work as intended?

Comment: Why do all the `Math.Abs()` instead of `s1.Length != s2.Length`?

Comment: yes, it is compiling and running, with some small tests i have made

Comment: @krillgar it suppose to check for a difference bigger than one. so "gilad" and "gilada" still return true, but "giladaa" will not

Comment: Ah, good point. I didn't think of that part. But shouldn't that be `> 1` then? Because if it differs by two, then it will not be caught there.

Comment: right LOL, my bad

Comment: @Gilad: I misinterpreted the assignment, disregard my answer.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel cool, Any other help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Gilad please clarify what differ by one character means. Do "ab" and "bac", for example, differ by one character or not? What about "abc" and "xcb"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Naming**

`CompareStrings()` and `CompareAllLetters` are poorly named. You **need** a comment to explain what the methods should achieve.

The input parameters `string stringToCheck1, string stringToCheck2` are also poorly named using some kind of hungarian style.

The input parameter of the `PrintMessage()` method is also poorly named. It is just not obvious what `result` should mean.

The same is true for the local variables `string1LettersList` and `string2LettersList`.

**Comments**

Comments should describe **why** something is done. The code should describe **what** is done.
This is especially true if the comment is plain wrong like `//check if strings are not the same size`. The check in question is not if they have a different size or not, it checks if the difference in length is greater than `2`.

**Simplifications**

- Use built in methods to simplify things.

  Like this

  > ```
  > List<char> string1LettersList = new List<char>();
  > foreach (var c in stringToCheck1)
  > {
  >     string1LettersList.Add(c);
  > }
  > ```

  can be simplified to

  ```
  List<char> string1LettersList = stringToCheck1.ToList<char>();
  ```
- returning booleans

  Like already mentioned in [vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40480/vnp)'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/71582/29371) you can simplify the returning of booleans. This is true for both of your methods.

  The condition in the `CompareStrings()` method is obviously flawed. If both strings are equal, it  would return `true`, so better change it to

  ```
  return (counter == 1);
  ```
- exit early

  You already do a check at the top of the methods (also it is done wrong), you can add another check for checking if both strings are the same.

  In the CompareStrings`()` method you can exit early if before the incremention `counter == 1` like

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < stringToCheck1.Length; i++)
  {
      if (stringToCheck1[i] != stringToCheck2[i])
      {
          if (counter == 1) { return false; }
          counter++;
      }
  }
  ```

**Code duplication**

In both methods you have the same (wrong) check about the size difference of the strings. You should extract this check to a separate method in which you also can integreate the check if both strings are the same.

```
private bool IsComparisonNeeded(String first, String second)
{
    if (first == second) { return false; }
    if (first == null || second == null) { return false; }

    return (Math.Abs(first.Length - second.Length) < 2);
}
```

**Bugs**

- if strings are same, both methods returns `true`
- if one or both of the strings is `null` the application crashes
- if the difference in `CompareAllLetters()` is `2` it returns `true`

**Refacoring**

Can't be done right now, because

- the code isn't producing the expected output
- it is not clear for which input which output should be expected.

**Suggestion**

For a problem like this, you should first write tests defining the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

I am not a C# expert, and leave an idiomatic review to those who are. Two general mistakes however strike immediately:

- Redundant logic

  ```
  if (condition)
      return false;
  else
      return true
  ```

  is equivalent to a single line

  ```
  return !condition;
  ```
- Time complexity

  The nested loops in `CompareAllLetters` make the complexity quadratic. Sorting the lists prior to compare drives complexity down to \$O(n\log n)\$

Comment: Great Answer! thanks I didn't even thought about complexity.

Comment: updated my answer, this is what you meant?

Comment: @Gilad: don't change your question. You can always post a followup question once you've incorporated the changes but changing it here invalidates answers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a relatively simple way using LINQ:

```
bool CompareStrings(string a, string b)
{
    int diff = a.Except(b).Count();
    if(a.Length != b.Length)
    {
        if(Math.Abs(a.Length - b.Length) > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (b.Length > a.Length && diff == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return diff == 1;
}
```

Comment: can you say what is the complexity of this?

Comment: @Gilad -Near as I can tell `Except` is O(n) and `Count` is O(1).

Comment: There's a bug: `CompareStrings("a", "a ")` returns false (while `CompareStrings("a", "ax")` returns true, as expected).

Comment: @Gilad - Oops missed that.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but there's another bug: `"aabc", "abd"` returns true.

Comment: Until the OP comes up with more definitive rules as to what should return true and what should return false, there will probably be lots of edge cases that don't work right.